# Python - pass variable to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to pass a variable into a `DataFrame` (ultimately to copy the variable to the system clipboard)

```
import sys
import dropbox
import pandas as pd
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('zzzzzzzzzzz')

def getSharedLink(full_path):
    try:
        link = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link(full_path).url
    except dropbox.exceptions.ApiError as err:
        print('*** API error', err)
        return None
df=pd.DataFrame("link")
df.to_clipboard(index=False,header=False)

getSharedLink("/z/z")
```

I know text should be formatted like (['text']) , I`m missing how I can use the variable "link" instead.